# Arithmetic expansion and parameter expansion

Tags: bash, arithmetic

```
$ x=foo; foo=bar; bar=6; 

$ echo $x
foo

$ echo $((x))
6
```

why can the arithmetic expansion trace from variable `x` to its value `foo`, from variable `foo` to its value `bar`, and then from variable `foo` to its value `6`, instead of stopping at the value `foo` of `x`?

Does it look like that arithmetic expansion applies `eval`  indefinitely many times to parameter expansion of the variable `x`, until reaching an integer or nothing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's an extension of `bash` (and also `zsh`, `ksh` and its derivatives) to allow shell variable contain invalid integer constant to be reused in arithmetic expression.

[From `bash` Shell Arithmetic](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Arithmetic):

> Shell variables are allowed as operands; parameter expansion is
>   performed before the expression is evaluated. Within an expression,
>   shell variables may also be referenced by name without using the
>   parameter expansion syntax. A shell variable that is null or unset
>   evaluates to 0 when referenced by name without using the parameter
>   expansion syntax. The value of a variable is evaluated as an
>   arithmetic expression when it is referenced, or when a variable which
>   has been given the integer attribute using ‘declare -i’ is assigned a
>   value. A null value evaluates to 0. A shell variable need not have its
>   integer attribute turned on to be used in an expression.

So in your case, `$((x))` first expanded `x` to `foo`, which is an invalid integer, so `foo` is reused as a variable name reference. Then `foo` was expanded to `bar`, the process above was repeated, until you got `6`, which is an valid integer.

---

POSIX spec only stated that `$((x))` and `$(($x))` will return the same value only when `x` is a valid integer constant. It does not say anything about the case `x` is an invalid integer, so shell implementations is free to handle this situation.

The result can be varied with different shells.

`zsh`, `ksh` and its derivatives behave like `bash` above (and also busybox `sh`).

`ash`, `dash` raise error if `x` contain invalid integer

```
$ x=foo foo=bar bar=6 dash -c 'echo "$((x))"'
dash: 1: Illegal number: foo
```

`yash` leaves the variable as-is:

```
$ x=foo foo=bar bar=6 yash -c 'echo "$((x))"'
foo
```

Comment: Thanks. In "The value of a variable is evaluated as an arithmetic expression when it is referenced, or when a variable which has been given the integer attribute using ‘declare -i’ is assigned a value", what does "when a variable which has been given the integer attribute using ‘declare -i’ is assigned a value " mean? I don't understand why it uses "a variable" instead of "the variable" to refer to  the same variable as "a variable" in "the value of a variable" at the beginning.