# How does arithmetic expansion work with variables without the $ (dollar) sign?

Tags: bash, arithmetic

I think the line below should be written differently, and the command should bug out.

```
$ echo $((x=2, y=3, x+y))
5
```

I thought the way to write this was:

```
$ echo $((x=2, y=3, $x+$y))
5
```

Both work, which now confuses me.  I'm assuming I have a mis-understanding somewhere, so I will explain how I decided the first echo is wrong.  The x+y is not referencing a variable, so how could bash possibly know that x and y are a variable.  If you tell me it's because of the $ at the start of the expression, then you must be wrong because x and y would have been defined at $x=2 and $y=2 which would be an incorrect way to define a variable.  So I have absolutely no idea how bash can know that x and y are variables.

Comment: IMO, not a dupe but related: [Arithmetic expansion and parameter expansion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/278670/arithmetic-expansion-and-parameter-expansion)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`man bash`, `ARITHMETIC EVALUATION` describes it as such:

> Shell variables are allowed as operands; parameter expansion is performed
> before the expression is evaluated.  Within an expression, shell variables
> may also be referenced by name without using the parameter expansion syntax.
> A shell variable that is null or unset evaluates to 0 when referenced by
> name without using the parameter expansion syntax.  The value of a variable
> is evaluated as an arithmetic expression when it is referenced […]

Within `$(())`, it can't be a command, string or anything else that the shell usually has to deal with, so it expands variables instead. It allows assignments so you are assigning variables.

However, it's actually your 2nd example that does not work:

```
$ echo $((x=2, y=3, $x+$y))
bash: x=2, y=3, +: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "+")
$ echo $((x=4, y=5, $x+$y))
5
```

In the first attempt, x and y was not assigned yet. In the second attempt it uses the previously assigned values, so you get an unexpected result (5 instead of 9).

When you use `$`, the shell expands it before arithmetic evaluation takes place. So assignments within arithmetic evaluation happen too late to affect `$` expansion.

It's also possible to do weird stuff like:

```
$ x=1+2+3
$ echo $x
1+2+3
$ echo $(($x*2))
9
$ echo $((x*2))
12
```

If you assign a variable outside of arithmetic evaluation, it's just a string. Then you use `$` and the shell expands it as a string. Then the arithmetic evaluation takes place and you have to deal with operator precedence.

Thus the result is `1+2+3*2 = 9` instead of `6*2 = 12`.

```
$ echo $((x=1+2+3, x*2))
12
$ echo $x
6
```

In this example the arithmetic evaluation takes place before assignment, so x=6 instead of x=1+2+3.

Comment: That is such a good answer,  The person who marked my one as duplicate should use this answer in place of the one linked, because this is FAR superior.  Nice one

Comment: The questions are similar but they ask about different corner cases. Your corner case is multiple expressions and assignments. The other question is regarding variable references inside variables. Since a variable may contain an arithmetic expression, and arithmetic expressions may use variables... the evaluation keeps going deeper and you can even produce a case of infinite recursion with foo=bar, bar=foo. Which accordingly yields an recursion level exceeded error...

Comment: +1, very nice answer.  This means that many answers on this site using shell arithmetic with `$` before the variable names are actually incorrect, they work by accident/circumstance rather than design.  e.g. compare `unset v; echo $((++v))` ("1") with `unset v; echo $((++$v)` (-bash: ++: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "+")).   I knew that variable names without `$` worked in shell arithmetic (including in array indices) but I never stopped to think about it or realise the danger in how it interacts with parameter expansion - I assumed it worked the same but was more readable.

Comment: I wouldn't say they are incorrect; they just have different semantics. Sometimes, you *want* an error if the variable isn't set. Consider something like `variableA=3`. `echo $((varaible + 3))` will silently output 3, since the mistyped variable will expand to 0. `echo $(( $varaible * 3 ))`, on the other hand, will produce an error because `$varaible` expands to the empty string, resulting in the syntactically invalid expression `* 3` being given to `$((...))`.

Comment: @chepner `set -u` might help catch typos in variable names

Comment: Indeed, but the behavior of `$((...))` is defined by POSIX, while `set -u` is a `bash` extension.