What's the difference between '$var' and 'var' in an arithmetic expansion?
Bash accepts both these syntax:
FOO=$(($BAR + 42))

and
FOO=$((BAR + 42))

Which one is correct / most portable / less prone to errors?  Or are both equally valid?

Also related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/728876/how-does-arithmetic-expansion-work-with-variables-without-the-dollar-sign

Also related: Security Implications of using unsanitized data in Shell Arithmetic evaluation

And: How to use associative arrays safely inside arithmetic expressions?

It depends on what you want to do, but you should validate any inputs used in arithmetic context first (see end).

Parameter expansions like $var and command substitutions are done before the arithmetic expression itself is parsed.(*)
That expansion happens without regard for the arithmetic syntax, so with $var you can mess with that.
On the other hand, without the $ sign, var is evaluated after the arithmetic expression is parsed, and must be something that evaluates to a value. It can be a complete expression though in Bash(**).
(* except some shells make exceptions so that something like $(( a[$key] = 1 )) works even if key is ].)
(** Most other shells also allow complete expressions in variables, but not e.g. Dash, the /bin/sh on Debian and Ubuntu.)

Hence, e.g. using $var can produce a syntax error if the variable is empty, while with var it will be treated as a zero.
$ echo $((10 - var))
10
$ echo $((10 - $var))
bash: 10 - : syntax error: operand expected (error token is "- ")

10 - $var produces just 10 -, an invalid expression. (This doesn't happen in your example of $BAR + 42 because + 42 is a valid expression.)
On the other hand, you an use $var to include partial expressions:
$ op=+; echo $(( 1 $op 2 ))
3

With var, you can only include complete subexpressions (in Bash):
$ var=1+2
$ echo $(( 10 *  var  ))
30

but note that using $var here would change the order of evaluation!
$ var=1+2
$ echo $(( 10 * $var  ))
12

Here, the variable is first expanded, giving 10 * 1+2, which is then parsed using the normal arithmetic rules, multiplication first, being the same as (10 * 1) + 2.
$(( 10 *  var  )) without the dollar sign effectively puts implicit parenthesis around the variable, so it's a bit like $(( 10 *  (1+2)  )).
As part of interpreting variables as full expressions, Bash will chase the chain of names if a variable names another:
$ one=two two=three three=four four=4; echo $(( one ))
4

The form without the dollar sign only works for actual named variables. If you want to use the positional parameters $1, $2... or special variables like $# or $? in arithmetic, you'll have to use the dollar form. (Which should be rather obvious, but still.)
See also Bash: Arithmetic expansion, parameter expansion, and the comma operator for another interesting difference.

While you should quote expansions  as usual, you don't need to quote variable expansions inside the arithmetic expression, and doing that would actually break many shells. So, do use "$(( ...))", but not $(( "$foo" )) (e.g. zsh croaks on i=123; echo $(( "$i" )))

Regardless of all that, note that Bash's arithmetic evaluation is vulnerable to trivial command injections in either case , like so:
$ var='a[$(date >&2)]'
$ echo $(( $var * 10 ))
Wed Aug 28 16:25:57 EEST 2024
0
$ echo $((  var * 10 ))
Wed Aug 28 16:26:49 EEST 2024
0

This means that if you get values from outside, you should validate them first, before using them in an arithmetic context. And if after that validation you know you have a plain number, it doesn't matter which form you use.
(This doesn't happen in Dash, since it doesn't support arrays, and zsh doesn't appear to fall for it.)

"Parameter expansions like $var and command substitutions are done before the arithmetic expression itself is parsed.". Not in all shells and all cases. For instance  a=']' ksh -c 'typeset -A b; echo "$(( b[$a] = 1 ))"; typeset -p b' doesn't report an error in recent versions of ksh93 or bash, though that remains flaky.
